# Snapshot Listener Permission Error while Signing Out - Kotlin/Firestore

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

This is my first time setting auth rules using Firestore, and I can't seem to figure out how to fix this problem. I apologize if this is a repeat, however I cannot find what I'm missing. When I logout of my app, I get a Permission Denied with the below code, even when I return the listener if there is an error. How can I prevent this from happening?

```
        db.collection("chats").whereEqualTo(currentUser, true)
            .addSnapshotListener {snapshot, error ->

                if (error != null) {
                    Log.e("ChatsFragment", "Error getting chats. Error: $error")
                    return@addSnapshotListener
                }

                if (snapshot!!.isEmpty) {
                    noMsgs.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                } else {
                    noMsgs.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            }
```

Here is my Logout just in case.

```
    AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this)
        .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                val intent = Intent(this, CheckUser::class.java)
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
                finish()
                handler.postDelayed({
                    startActivity(intent)
                    Toast.makeText(this, "You have been logged out.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }, 1000)
            } else {
                val intent = Intent(this, CheckUser::class.java)
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
                finish()
                startActivity(intent)
                Log.e("LogoutActivity", "Error logging out. ${task.exception?.message.toString()}")
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yes, queries that require authentication in security rules will immediately fail when the user is signed out.  Are you expecting something different?

Comment: I realize I was not very thorough with my question. I want to prevent this error. Is there something in my code I am doing wrong or forgetting. I have tried to add listeners and then remove listeners, but still have the same problem. Majority of what I read to prevent this, has to do with changing or modifying my database rules, and I can't do that.

Comment: You can't stop a query from failing if the rules reject it.  All you can do is detect the error and deal with it.

Comment: I feel like a dummy... My app was crashing, during the sign-out process, but the only error I was receiving was the Permissions Denied error. After I commented out my query just to check if that was the problem, I caught the real error. Fixed it, and my query and sign-out  process is working properly!

Comment: Good to hear you figured it out Chris. If you get a similar error on the future, you may need to [detach the listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener) before signing out.